# explicit equation for a recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the  sequence: ($a_1=-1 ,a_{n+1}=a_n+2n , n\in N$)

I'm trying to find an explicit equation for this sequence. I am not familiar to how to find closed form of a recursive sequence so I tried to write first terms of the sequence:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
n:&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
a_n:&-1&1&5&11&19&29
\end{array}$$

And form here I guessed there is a relation between $n^2$ and $a_n$. and after trying some equations I got: $$a_n=n^2-n-1$$

But as I said earlier, I don't know how to write explicit equation of a recursive sequence. So how can I find this equation mathematically? and how can I learn some basic technics to convert such a sequence to explicit one?(looking for some resources)

Comment: You can see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving) for solving recurrence relations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have for all $k \geq 1$
$$a_{k+1}-a_k = 2k$$

so if you sum these equalities for $k=1, ..., n-1$, you get
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (a_{k+1}-a_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 2k$$
i.e.
$$a_n-a_1 = n(n-1)$$
i.e. finally because $a_1=-1$,
$$a_n=n^2-n-1$$

Comment: Is this relevant to telescoping series?

Comment: Yes, the way from step 2 to step 3 is a telecoping trick.

Comment: Do we usually use this method for some simple recursive sequences or there are other tricks ?

Comment: It really depends. There is no general method to express a recursive sequence directly in terms of $n$. It happens very frequently that it is purely impossible.

Comment: Oh I got it. Thank you.

Comment: If $a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ goes like $n^k$, $k \in N$ then $a_n$ goes like $n^{k+1}$.

Comment: @cosmo5 Yes, but the OP asks about explicit expression of $a_n$ in term of $n$.

Comment: Yes, I was telling him about nature of difference - linear, quadratic etc.

Comment: @Aryadeva The sum $1+2+... +n$ is equal to $n(n+1)/2$. You can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF for example. Or you can try to prove it by induction. Tell me if you have some difficulties proving this famous identity.

Comment: Yes sorry @TheSilverDoe +1

Answer (score 1):

Observe the finite differences of the first 6 values of the series.

[image]

After $2$ iterations of successive finite differences, the differences become constant. Therefore, the polynomial that generates the sequence has degree 2.

Let $a(n) = An^2 + Bn + C$.

Use $a(0), a(1)$ and $a(2)$ for $n = 1, 2, 3$ respectively and obtain a system of equations for variables $A, B, C$ and solve them. (You could use any three values of $n$).

Here's the [worked solution for the example on WolframALpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20A*1%20%2B%20B*1%20%2B%20C%20%3D%20-1%2C%20A*2%5E2%20%2B%20B*2%20%2B%20C%20%3D%201%2C%20A*3%5E2%20%2B%20B*3%20%2B%20C%20%3D%205):
This gives $A = 1, B = -1, C = -1$.

So, $a(n) = n^2 - n - 1$

Comment: Ok, the differences are $2n$. so differences are $\{2,4,6,8,\cdots\}$ and finding differences again we have $\{2,2,2,\cdots\}$. doing that again we have all zeros. But I don't understand how we conclude the polynomial that generates the sequence has degree $2$ from this.

Comment: For the values generated by a polynomial of degree $n$, after $n$ successive iterations, the difference becomes constant. See: Newton's Interpolation formula of finite differences.